# Absence of certain data in my Looker Studio table

Tags: looker-studio

I created a table on Data Looker using a database with over 3 million rows. However, Data Looker only manages to display 150,000 rows. I am wondering if there is a maximum limit on the number of rows that can be displayed.

I want to be able to display all the rows of this table on Data Looker.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Looker Studio has an inherent limit that will only display up to 1 million rows

[Tables help center][1]

Unfortunately you are limited to 150k if you are using the Microsoft SQL Server connector and presumably other connectors. So it is possibly your connector that is limiting the rows and not Looker studio itself.

[Looker support][2]

I would suggest that Looker studio a data visualization tool and is not the right tool to process 3 million lines. If your data is less than 2 GIG Power BI might be able to handle it but looking into Bigquery or MYSQL might be your best option.
[1]: https://support.google.com/area120-tables/answer/10145198?hl=en&sjid=4909395076644877839-EU
[2]: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/11283389?hl=en#limits&zippy=%2Cin-this-article